# How to select the records from a table which is not in the result of select Query(select query might be joins of 2 or more tables)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider:

```
table t1(a,b,c)
table t2(a,d,e)
table t3(r,f,g)

select t1.a,t1.b,t1.c,t2.d,t2.e
from t1 join t2
on (t1.a=t2.a)
```

And also need to select records from t3 table which are not in above query result on the basis of t1.a and t3.r

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relation between `t1.a` and `t3.r` then just have a join between the tables like

```
select t1.a,
       t1.b,
       t1.c,
       t2.d,
       t2.e,
       t3.g
from t1 
join t2 on t1.a = t2.a
join t3 on t1.a = t3.r;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relation between `t1.a` and `t3.r` then:

```
SELECT t1,*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.a
JOIN t3 ON 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `NOT IN` in the `WHERE` clause, along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    t3.*
FROM
    t3 AS t3
WHERE
    t3.r NOT IN
        (select t1.a
         from t1 join t2
         on (t1.a=t2.a))
```